# How to allow comma when inputting numeric value

Tags: ruby

I tried to sum two floating point numbers. When I use `"."` as the delimiter between decimals, it works correctly. But, when I use a comma, the last two numbers return zero. Example:

```
puts "Type the first number:"
firstNum = gets.to_f # I typed 55,11

puts "Type the second number:"
secondNum = gets.to_f # I typed 45,44

result = firstNum +  secondNum

puts sprintf('%.2f', result)  # Return 100.00
```

If I use `"."` to separate the numbers, the return is `100.55`.

Comment: In ruby decimal deparator is a dot, regardless of what it is for your current computer locale.

Comment: That's normal behaviour. What's your question?

Answer (score 2):

[`Fixnum#to_f`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_f) expects dots. To allow commas you should do convert them to commas explicitly:

```
puts "Type the first number:"
#               ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
firstNum = gets.tr(',', '.').to_f # I typed 55,11

puts "Type the second number:"
#                ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
secondNum = gets.tr(',', '.').to_f # I typed 45,44

result = firstNum +  secondNum

puts sprintf('%.2f', result)  # Return 100.55
```

Comment: Let's hope we don't have a user who enters `1,234.56`.